# SEO optimization for every subdomain blog.exampledomain.com vs. www.exampledomain.com/blog?

Tags: seo, subdomain

We are hosting our blog under **blog.exampledomain.com** and a SEO consultant suggested to move it to
**www.exampledomain.com/blog** because SEO has to be done for every subdomain.

**BACKGROUND INFO:**

www.exampledomain.com ... Landingpage

alpha.exampledomain.com ... Webapplication

blog.exampledomain.com ... Blog

**Is this true?**

What happens we also make the content available at the www.exampledomain.com/blog? (As far i know duplicate content is really bad)

What steps are necessary to move it there? (if necessary)

Any other points that we should consider from SEO perspective?

Comment: You should either trust your SEO specialist, or find a new one. FWIW, **blog.example.com** is considered to be a different site than **www.example.com**. **example.com/blog** is considered to be a sub-page of **example.com**.

Comment: To avoid the duplicate content problem, your SEO specialist will probably redirect `blog.domain.com` to `domain.com/blog`.

Comment: There are several factors that go into making a decision like this and should not be done too blindly. If the bulk if the site is the blog and the blog is focused, then it would be better in a sub-directory but moving it would depend on how established the blog is. If it has been in place a long time and you have links and are ranking well, you are likely far better off leaving it where it is. Your consultant isn't wrong exactly, it is just a mistake to make blanket statements like this.

Comment: Thank you. The Blog is not that established with not so much links. I think 301 redirect should be ok.

Comment: Thank you.
I found following article to the topic http://www.bloggingflail.com/subdomains-vs-subdirectories/
and makes sense for me, but not a full proof of concept.
What do you think?
Our Wordpress will contain content to a broad area of articles related to entrepreneural life. 
I think the way for us is to move our subdomain to a subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

If you move your blog to a subdomain, you shouldn't, by any means, keep it in the folder due to duplicate content problems. You can only move it, not copy it.

About your question, for my experience it's not true and you should keep your blog where it is right now.
This happens because the main domain has the main strength and power and dividing it to subdomains will only dilute this position. Subdmomains are great for separate panels, logins, user areas where you'll want, for example to have separate access control.
I did some research and found a reply from Rand Fishkin from moz.com that backs up my position:

> I would still strongly urge folks to keep all content on a single
>   subdomain. We recently were able to test this using a subdomain on Moz
>   itself (when moving our beginner's guide to SEO from guides.moz.com to
>   the current URL http://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo). The results
>   were astounding - rankings rose dramatically across the board for
>   every keyword we tracked to the pages.
>
> I've had the opportunity to see many dozens of other sites do the
>   same, almost always with similarly positive results (assuming they're
>   moving from a subdomain without much other content/link signals to the
>   subdomain that has those signals).

Taken from [here](http://moz.com/community/q/moz-s-official-stance-on-subdomain-vs-subfolder-does-it-need-updating).

[Here](http://moz.com/learn/seo/domain) is also a greate resource from Moz about domains.

Comment: Part of what you quoted from MOZ makes sense for a site of that scale. But not all sites are that large, involved, or can afford to have the bulk of their content on a sub-domain. However, to support your thought, if the blog is highly focused and the bulk of the site, then it is better in a sub-directory, however, if the blog is not as focused and the site has good content, then it may be a better idea to have it on a sub-domain.

Comment: I don't see how scale relates with this problem. Either you have a good domain with a complementary subfolder for a blog or you're spreading the strength to a subdomain. What do you mean by "the blog is highly focused"? I'm having some problems understanding the relations you make in your comment, mainly the concept of bulk and focused.

Comment: Some blog topics are not as focused as others. Some are designed to remain within a narrow topic window with specific keyword signals per post. Other blogs are more free flow and do not focus on keywords and topics windows as much. As well, a small site with little content where the blog is the bulk of the content, the blog should be on the site and not on a sub-directory. These are somewhat general and a look at the site and blog are required to really make a decision. Moz is large enough that moving segments of the site to sub-directories would allow more focused content to perform better.

Comment: I now kind of see your point but honestly don't think that having "narrow" or "broad" content can relate to having the blog on a subdomain or folder. I'm sorry to say but I find your theory a little bit overly refined. It's just a blog with content related to the site and it's more important to have a good, fast, high quality blog than thinking too much about if it's focused or not. Also the concept of "focused" is ambiguous as I might find my blog "narrow" but the Search Engine not and vice-versa.

Comment: I am not arguing. I kind of think of a focused blog as one that search engines agree are focused. ;-) And certainly the state of a site is never really fixed. I could start a blog that is not necessarily focused and modify it to be more focused or the opposite, keep adding and sometime coloring out of the lines. Each case is unique and a clean look has to be made. I do not think I would move a blog from a sub-domain that has existed for a while. I was just saying that sometimes there are reasons that a change would be good. I am not an absolutist on this topic. I agree with you.

Comment: No, not at all, mate :) I'm just having a hard time seeing the concept of narrowing. For ex: Sports -> Outdoor Sports -> Two Wheels -> Bicycle -> Acessories -> Helmets. What is narrow here? I might think that writing about Bicycles is narrow but for the Search Engine only Bicycle helmets are. This is the type of question I see had to reply and in the core of my doubts. Anyway let's leave this for other question as we are out of the original subject. Cheers!

Comment: I see where I went wrong! I mean *narrow* as in SEO keyword search performance wise and not necessarily topic wise. My mistake! Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you guys for the open discussions. SEO topics are so esoteric sometimes.
I found following article to the topic http://www.bloggingflail.com/subdomains-vs-subdirectories/
and makes sense for me, but not a full proof of concept.
What do you think?
Our Wordpress will contain content to a broad area of articles related to entrepreneural life. 
I think the way for us is to move our subdomain to a subfolder.

Comment: @cubix I agree with the link you provided that basically defends the same as me. The final answer to your problem will depend if the blog is already well indexed and with a lot of content.

Comment: Whatever I read case study online about that, it does not make sense to me, because they have never links their sub domain to domain and main domain to subdomain. Also many of people say they get boost in traffic after moving to directory, but in reality those sites was using nofollow links internally . Also [Google consider your subdomain to domain links are internal](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2011/08/reorganizing-internal-vs-external.html), then how it can be consider as separate site?

Comment: John Muller said hundred times in Google official hangout, feel free to choose anything like sub domain or sub directory, We will consider that links internally it means all of factor will transfer same. So I believe there is no reason to said any wrong statement like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use it at `blog.example.com`, it will be treated as another website.  If you put it on a subfolder, it will be treated as part of website. This will impact the content of the website, inbound links, pages, backlinks, and everything else.

Conclusion: it is better in a subfolder then on a subdomain. You have to remove the content on a subdomain because it will be treated as duplicated content.